# Create view action in gridview

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How to make just view action in my gridview,I already have list of my data and view button, but I want to see different record when click that view button. Now I see only error and my url change for id of that records like /index/0 or /index/1.

```
<?php
use yii\grid\GridView;
?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'ID'=>'id',
        'Title'=>'post_title',
        'Text'=>'post_text',
        'Author'=>'name',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'header'=>'Действия',
            'headerOptions' => ['width' => '80'],
            'template' => '{view}',
        ],
    ],
    'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
return ['id' => $model['id']];
    },
]); ?>
```

I have that error:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request: site/error' in W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php:125
Stack trace:
#0 W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(454): yii\base\Controller->runAction('error', Array)
#1 W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(93): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/error')
#2 W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(109): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\NotFoundHttpException))
#4 {main}
Previous exception:
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request: site/view' in W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php:125
Stack trace:
#0 W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(454): yii\base\Controller->runAction('view', Array)
#1 W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(100): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/view', Array)
#2 W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#3 W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#4 {main}

Next exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Page not found.' in W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php:112
Stack trace:
#0 W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 W:\XAMPP\htdocs\test\basic\index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, you should include that error in your question.

Comment: Of course I have error, my controller doesn't handle url like http://localhost/basic/site/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you don't have a view name view.php  in your site/view

be sure you have a viewAction in your site Controller

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
   ....
    // this is only a sample
   public function actionView($id)
   {
       return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
       ]);
    }
    ...
}
```

And a view.php  in your   yourAppName/views/site/ directory